# How could I reenable Silverlight designer in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-toolkit

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2008. When I installed vs2010 rc1 some strange error messages appeared when I opened a silverlight3 solution in vs2008, I told it not to show it again, but I remember it have some strange guid keys.

I have reinstalled everything and it keep showing no silverlight designer when I open a xaml, but the solution work well and I can execute it normally, but I have no xaml intellisense and preview (it just appears with black character as in notepad).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using vs 2010 rc1, I did not got any strange error and it works for me as smooth but it crashes a browser lot for the web application.:( .. vs 2010 supports sl4.And you can see  silverlight designer.

So please remove sl4 if you have installed and install it again.

Comment: No no, it breaked my vs2008 sl3 applications

Comment: I too use vs 2008 with sl3 and it doesn't breaks for me. Yes but you can't see the preview of your xaml design. 

It was there in sl2 , they removed it in sl3 and they have kept it in sl4 . :)